# quantum random number generator implementation in quantum lab

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

How can I generate and print a 32 bit sequence of 0s and 1s in Qiskit or IBM Q experience quantum lab using quantum random number generator implementation?

Comment: Have you got any thoughts about how you want to go about doing this? Do you want to randomly generate a bit at a time, where the randomness comes from measurement outcomes, or would you rather do something more complicated, like generate a large random unitary and act with that on some input state?

Comment: i am looking to generate bit using randomness in measurement and also like to observe the bit sequence obtained for randomness  for different cases  using 1/2/3/4/6 qubit measurement

Answer (score 1):

Qiskit [0.21](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/releases/tag/0.21.0) has [qiskit-ibmq-provider 0.9](https://pypi.org/project/qiskit-ibmq-provider/0.9.0/). This new provider comes with a connector to the RNG service in IBMQ. From the release notes:

> You can now access the IBMQ random number services, such as the CQC
> randomness extractor, using the new package
> qiskit.providers.ibmq.random. Note that this feature is still in beta,
> and not all accounts have access to it. It is also subject to heavy
> modification in both functionality and API without backward
> compatibility.

You can find the documentation [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/ibmq_random.html) and [here](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit_rng).

Comment: Looks like not anymore

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to generate uniformly distributed sequence of bits. In such case you can apply a Hadamard gates on $n$ qubits, where $n$ is number of bits you want to have in your sequence.

Application of Hadamard gates on $n$ qubits in state $|0\rangle$ will lead to state
$$
H^{\otimes n}|0\rangle ^{\otimes n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{i=0}^{2^n-1}|i\rangle,
$$
i.e. you get equally distributed superposition of all bit strings of length $n$.

After measurement you will get a random sequence of $n$ bits.

Comment: what should i do if i want a 512 bit random sequence as number of qubits available are less. is there a way of repeating the measurements so that i can generate a larger bit sequence using less qubits.

Comment: @parth: Just idea, run the circuit many times, extract $n$ random bits in each run and them put them in one serie.